# Error al substituir los valores NaN por la moda si todos los valores de la columna son NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Hola a todos y gracias por su tiempo, requiero actualizar los valores nulos con la moda de la variable pero se debe agrupar por 2 variables específicas, solo se actualizará unas variables categóricas específicas que tengo en un arreglo:

```
camposCateg = ['ESTADO_PARTICIPANTE', 'ESTRATO']
group = df1.groupby(['COMPONENTE','PROYECTO' ], group_keys=False)
for col in camposCateg:
   if col in df1.columns and df1[col].notna().sum() > 0:
    df1[col] = group[col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
df1.info()
```

Dentro del `for` adicioné un `if` que si la suma de los registros es mayor a cero se aplica el remplazar el valor de los nulos con la moda pero genera el error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Probé colocando en `camposCateg`  una variable que no tiene valores nulos y no genera error pero pude observar que hay casos `ESTADO_PARTICIPANTE` que al agrupar componente y proyecto toda la información está vacía y por esta razón no se podría calcular la moda.

Adicioné dentro del `for` un `if` que si la suma de los registros es mayor a cero se aplica el remplazar el valor de los nulos con la moda, pero igual sigue mostrando el mismo error, el motivo por el cual es posible que no haya datos es porque en algunos años no se cargó esa información.

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df1[col].notna().sum() > 0` determina si hay al menos un valor no `NaN` en la columna, pero ten en cuenta que `fillna` y por tanto `mode` **se aplica por cada grupo**. Puedes tener una columna con algunos valores que no sean `NaN` pero que uno de los grupos coincida que tenga todos sus valores de esa columna como `NaN`, por ejemplo:

```
  Foo  Bar
0   A  4.0
1   A  NaN
2   B  NaN
3   A  4.0
4   B  NaN
5   A  2.0
```

Si agrupamos por *Foo*, podemos calcular la moda de la columna *Bar* para el grupo  *Foo=A* pero no para *Foo=B*, porque todos los valores de la columna *Bar* para este grupo son `NaN`.

En vez de hacer la comprobación a nivel de toda la columna, puedes hacerla en cada grupo, por ejemplo:

```
for col in camposCateg:
    df1[col] = group[col].apply(
        lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]) if not x.isna().all() else x
        )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración, muy clara, ya probé y verifiqué resultados y efectivamente lo hizo correctamente